# Permission denied when setting up and running PostgreSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion

I am completely new to postgres and web development. I am on a fresh install of MAC OSX 10.7 Lion and I am told that PostgreSQL does in fact come packaged in. This is what I get when I type 'psql' in terminal.

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I did not install PostgreSQL myself using any package manager. I'm just using what Lion came with. Unfortunately I can't even setup a DB.

Note: I don't have MacPorts installed.

Comment: You'll need to start the PostgreSQL server. It appears as though it's currently not running. Probably `pg_ctl start`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get:     
    -bash: pg_ctl: command not found

Comment: Does this help? http://www.luckydonkey.com/2008/07/03/mac-osx-starting-postgres-on-boot/

Comment: Unfortunately no. I get: sudo: /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl: command not found.

Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Do you think if I do a fresh install using HomeBrew, it would help? If so, do I need to uninstall the default PostgreSQL?